# funcion no definida en javascript

Tags: javascript, formularios, undefined

lo que necesito es saber porque me sale que la funcion capturar no está definida en el elemnto buttononlickhtml, si el archivo js está correctamente configurado y los nombres estan bien puestos,si agrego un console log en el js me sale normal en la pagina, entonces el js funciona correctamente, el formulario solo es a puro javascript como tarea de la universidad, cualquier ayuda les agradezco, poruqe ayer la funcion se ejecutaba con otro codigo pero no almacenaba temporalmente la variable global, ( lo que quiere decir que si estaba definida)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>modulo17</title>
    
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/cuenta.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
    
    <h1>
        Sucursal virtual del Banco Nacional
    </h1>
    <p>
        <br>
        Bienvenido a la Sucursal virtual del Banco Nacional<br>
        <br> Aquí puede retirar, depositar y consultar su saldo cada vez que lo desee.<br>
    </p>

    <form id ="Movimientos">
        <fieldset >
            <legend>Crear cuenta: </legend>
            
            <div>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="identidad">Documento de identidad:
                    <input type="number" name="identidad" id="identidad" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="telefono">Telefono:
                    <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email">Email:
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
            <button id ="enviar" type="submit" onclick="capturar()">Enviar</button>         
            </div>


        </fieldset>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Datos de la cuenta: </legend>

            <div>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="numerodecuenta">Número de cuenta:
                    <input type="number" name="numerodecuenta" id="numerodecuenta">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="clave">Clave:
                    <input type="password" name="clave" id="clave">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id ="saldo" type="submit" onclick="datos()">Consultar saldo</button>         
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id ="desactivar" type="submit" >Desactivar cuenta</button>         
            </div>

            <div>
                <button id ="reactivar" type="submit" >Reactivar cuenta</button>         
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="valordeposito">Valor a depositar:
                    <input type="number" name="valordeposito" id="valordeposito">
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="valorretiro">Valor a retirar:
                    <input type="number" name="valorretiro" id="valorretiro">
                </label>
            </div>

            
            <div>
                <button id ="enviar" type="submit" onclick="depositar()">Enviar</button>         
            </div>
             
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Resultados:    </legend>
            <div>
                <label for="valordepositado">El valor depositado exitosamente es:
                    <input type="number" name="valordepositado" id="valordepositado" readonly>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="valorretirado">El valor retirado exitosamente es:
                    <input type="number" name="valorretirado" id="valorretirado" readonly>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="saldo">El saldo actual de su cuenta es:
                    <input type="number" name="saldo" id="saldo" readonly>
                </label>
            </div>
        </fieldset>

        <fieldset>
            <legend>Número de transacciones </legend>
            <div>
                <label for="cantdeposito">Cantidad de depositos realizados:
                    <input type="number" name="cantdeposito" id="cantdeposito" readonly>
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="cantretiro">Cantidad de retiros realizados:
                    <input type="number" name="cantretiro" id="cantretiro" readonly>
                </label>
            </div>

            


        </fieldset>
    </form>
    
</body>
```

```
nombre = "",
identidad="",
telefono= "",
email= "",

function capturar(){

nombre= document.getElementById("nombre").value;
identidad= document.getElementById("identidad").value;
telefono= document.getElementById("telefono").value;
email= document.getElementById("email").value
    

console.log(nombre,identidad,email,telefono);

})
    
}
```

Comment: No se si será eso, pero los script se ponen al final del body

Comment: Tambien falta un ; despues de email= document.getElementById("email").value

Comment: Esto se da por el orden en que se cargan el doom una solucion es usar window.load, moverlos al final o agregar el atributo deferrer

Comment: no es nada de eso, sigue diciendo que no está difnido y si agrego otras cosas al js, funcionan bien pero la funcion ni se ejecuta

Answer (score 0):

Algunas cosas:

- La etiqueta `<script>` debe ir en el `<head>` con la propiedad `defer` o en su defecto, al final del `<body>`. Ponerla al inicio ocasiona que se ejecute primero el JS y luego el html del body, por lo tanto, si intenta seleccionar a un elemento del DOM que se encuentre después del `<script>`, este retornara un `null`.
- Los ID deben ser únicos, por lo que utilizar el mismo en varios elementos retornara un error en consola.
- No se recomienda utilizar la propiedad on-click, lo mejor es referenciar el elemento declarando una constante: `const btn = document.querySelector("#enviar")`.
- Para obtener los datos, cuando se envíe el formulario, necesita añadir el evento `submit`, así: `form.addEventListener("submit", () => {})`.
- Para evitar que se recargue la página al enviar el formulario, se debe añadir el método `preventDefault()` dentro del anterior evento.
- Yo creo que lo mejor sería declarar varios formularios para cada bloque(crear cuenta, actualizar datos, resultados).

**Ejemplo:**

```js
const form = document.querySelector("#mov");

let nombre = "";
let identidad= "";
let telefono= "";
let email= "";

function capturar(){
     form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
          e.preventDefault();

          nombre= document.getElementById("nombre").value;
          identidad= document.getElementById("identidad").value;
          telefono= document.getElementById("telefono").value;
          email= document.getElementById("email").value

          console.log(nombre,identidad,email,telefono);
          alert("--Nombre: "+nombre+" --Identidad: "+identidad+" --Telefono: "+telefono+"  --Email: "+email);
     })
}

capturar();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>modulo17</title>
    <script defer src="main.js"></script>   
</head>
<body>
    <form id ="mov">
        <fieldset >
            <legend>Crear cuenta: </legend>
            
            <div>
                <label for="nombre">Nombre:
                    <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="identidad">Documento de identidad:
                    <input type="number" name="identidad" id="identidad" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="telefono">Telefono:
                    <input type="number" name="telefono" id="telefono" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
                <label for="email">Email:
                    <input type="text" name="email" id="email" >
                </label>
            </div>

            <div>
            <button id ="enviar" type="submit">Enviar</button>         
            </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Espero que el ejemplo le sea de ayuda.